# Forward http to https - Elastic Beanstalk + Nginx

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk with a Node.js server, Load Balanced, and Nginx proxy. I want all addresses http://example.com to be rerouted to https://example.com.

I have tried the config below which lives in .ebextensions and looks like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
```

My Load Balancer has 80 pointing to 80 and 443 pointing to 80:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear what exactly is going wrong, but maybe you could use the x-forwarded-proto in a rewrite condition.

I haven't tried this myself, but maybe something like: [how to redirect http to https in nginx docker elastic beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716786/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx-docker-elastic-beanstalk)